# Passing characters to a components ignores spaces in React Js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have been working on a React component that takes in a paragraph(string) and passes each character to another. But the spaces don't seem to appear when I use flex in Tailwind CSS. Without flex, all the characters appear vertically. Here *apiResponse* is the string with spaces.

```
return(
  <div className="w-3/4 flex flex-wrap">
      {apiResponse.split('').map(function(char, index){
        return <Character key={index}>{char}</Character>;
    })}
  </div>
```

)

The code for Character component is

```
const Character = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="bg-green-100">
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Character;
```

[image]

How to rectify this error with Tailwind CSS? Or is something wrong with the JS code?

Comment: Actually adding a container "Word" and splitting the sentence into words before Characters allowed me to wrap properly around words and not individual characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divs with only space are treated as `<div />` and not displayed.
You could try something like this

```
return(
  <div className="w-3/4 flex flex-wrap">
      {apiResponse.split('').map(function(char, index){
        return <Character key={index}>{char === ' ' ? '\u00A0' : char}</Character>;
    })}
  </div>
```

or you could use `span` instead of `div`

Comment: The '\u00A0' worked, but using span instead of div didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

If you put a single space " " in an element, it won't take any space. Example:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>a</div><div>b</div><div>c</div>
  <div> </div>
  <div>a</div><div>b</div><div>c</div>
</div>
```

What you can use instead is the `\u00A0` character (unicode equivalent of `&nbsp;`). You can replace all space characters with `\u00A0` in your React code like so:

```js
const Character = ({ children }) => (
  <div class="character">
    { children === " " ? "\u00A0" : children }
  </div>
);

const App = () => {
  const apiResponse = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
  return (
    <div className="paragraph">
      {apiResponse.split('').map((char, index) =>
        <Character key={index}>{char}</Character>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.paragraph {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: oops... i started writing this answer before the other was posted, sorry about that!

Comment: I think no-one has a problem with that, sorry for stealing your time to shine